# ViewModelFactory need

Tags: android, kotlin, design-patterns, android-viewmodel

I'm doing some codelabs of [kotlin fundamentals](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/android-kotlin-fundamentals/) and I don't really get in android with the ViewModel why sometimes there seems to be a need of creating it through a ViewModelFactory. [Here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-view-model/index.html?index=..%2F..android-kotlin-fundamentals#7) you can see the [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-view-model/index.html?index=..%2F..android-kotlin-fundamentals#7) which talks about this.

They just say to perform the initialization using the [factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) but I don't understand the why. Why do we need to use factory pattern? Is it because we need to pass some parameter to the ViewModel? Or is it for some other reason? Is every time we need to create a ViewModelFactory just to pass parameters to the ViewModel?

I've been looking for the answer, trying to confirm whether is just to pass extra parameters or is because of any other reason but still I'm not sure and I haven't found the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that need to consider before using `ViewModel` and `ViewModelFactory`

1. `ViewModel` is `LifecycleAware Components`.
2. `ViewModel` survive `configuration` changes.
3. `ViewModelProvider' can only instantiate`ViewModel` with no-args contructor.

> Why do we need to use factory pattern?

To instantiate `ViewModel` with arguments need to use `ViewModelFactory`. `ViewModelProviders` Utility can not create an instance of a ViewModel with argument constructor because it does not know how and what objects to pass in the constructor.

Also, you should follow the Dependency Injection principle. A class should not create dependencies it needs. It should be provided rather than creating.

For Example -

```
public class LogInViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final LogInRepo repo;
    public LogInViewModel (LogInRepo repo) {
         /* this.repo = new LogInRepo(); Not recommended, It violates DI principle*/
         this.repo = repo;
    }
}
```

Comment: The ViewModel is lifecycle-aware and survives configuration changes even though you don't use a ViewModelFactory, if I'm not wrong

Comment: ViewModel does not hold any references to activity and due to that `ViewModel` will not be able to survive configuration changes.

Comment: You pass an activity or fragment in `ViewModelProviders.of` and there is no need of a ViewModelFactory to survive configuration changes

Comment: Yeah, you are right `ViewModelFactory` can be skipped if your `ViewModel` have a no-args constructor. With use of this method `ViewModelProviders.of(this)`.

Comment: I mark your aswer as correct because it has helped and clarified many things but you still can remove that paragraph from the answer or edit it if you want. Thank you so much for your explanation, very helpful

Comment: Can we have a  generic ViewModelFactory class for all the ViewModels in an App ? And can we make the ViewModelFactory class as singleton ?